# How to access LayoutManager from RecyclerView.Adapter to get scrollToPosition?

Tags: java, android, scala, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I customized `RecyclerView` by adding separate layouts for header and footer. I created constants to determine the property of header, footer and list item in the adapter class. I also created a ViewHolder pattern and assign the layouts to be shown based on the view type. I fixed the header at zeroth position and footer at last position of the array by override `getItemViewType` method.

I want to make the footer element clickable, so I assign a `setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())` and overwrote `onClick(view: View)`

My goal is to click on the footer and `scrollToPosition` 0 or 1 (0 = Header, 1 = first item element).

That's MyAdapter definition:

```
class MyAdapter(context: Context, data: Array[String]) extends RecyclerView.Adapter[RecyclerView.ViewHolder]

...

override def onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int): Unit = holder match {
  ...
  case holder:FooterViewHolder =>
    holder.backToTop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      override def onClick (view: View) {
        backToTop(???)
        Toast.makeText (context, "Clicked Footer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
    })
  ...
}
...
```

I read I just need to do this: `recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position)`

Unfortunately I can't access the LayoutManager from my Adapter class. Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Pass LayoutManage in adapter using constructor of Adapter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make constuctor of MyAdapter as follow.

```
 MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(context,list,mLayoutManager);
```

Answer (score 31):

Another approach

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
}
```